# Is this some sort of race condition I created with Swift

Tags: swift, race-condition

I have a simple SwiftUI example that moves a block down the screen X pixels each time a timer fires; I wrote the code out in full.

issued here can be considered to be zero; vertiSide + horizSide are just reference numbers.

Now this works, but I want to execute it in a loop.

```
fileprivate func extractedFunc() {
    let t3 = "\(tileP[0 + issued].vertiSide - 32)\(tileP[0 + issued].horizSide)"
    if let ok = tileD[t3] {
        if !ok {
            var t0 = "\(tileP[0 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[0 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t0] = false
            tileP[0 + issued].vertiSide -= 32
            var t1 = "\(tileP[0 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[0 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t1] = true
            
            t0 = "\(tileP[1 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[1 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t0] = false
            tileP[1 + issued].vertiSide -= 32
            t1 = "\(tileP[1 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[1 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t1] = true
            
            t0 = "\(tileP[2 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[2 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t0] = false
            tileP[2 + issued].vertiSide -= 32
            t1 = "\(tileP[2 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[2 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t1] = true
            
            t0 = "\(tileP[3 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[3 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t0] = false
            tileP[3 + issued].vertiSide -= 32
            t1 = "\(tileP[3 + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[3 + issued].horizSide)"
            tileD[t1] = true
        }
    }
}
```

So I wrote this code, which does the same thing [I thought]

```
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let t3 = "\(tileP[0].vertiSide - 32)\(tileP[0].horizSide)"
                for i in 0..<tileP.count {
                    semaphore.wait()
                        
                        if let ok = tileD[t3] {
                            if !ok  {
                                let t0 = "\(tileP[i].vertiSide)\(tileP[i].horizSide)"
                                tileD[t0] = false
                                tileP[i].vertiSide -= 32
                                let t1 = "\(tileP[i].vertiSide)\(tileP[i].horizSide)"
                                tileD[t1] = true
                            }
                        }
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
```

But the output is very different, for version 1 I get this for the tileD array.

```
Optional(false) 512.00.0
Optional(false) 480.00.0
Optional(false) 448.00.0
Optional(false) 416.00.0
Optional(false) 384.00.0
Optional(false) 352.00.0
Optional(false) 320.00.0
Optional(false) 288.00.0
Optional(false) 256.00.0
Optional(false) 224.00.0
Optional(false) 192.00.0
Optional(false) 160.00.0
Optional(false) 128.00.0
Optional(true) 96.00.0
Optional(true) 64.00.0
Optional(true) 32.00.0
Optional(true) 0.00.0
```

But for version 2 I get this for the output

```
Optional(true) 512.00.0
Optional(true) 480.00.0
Optional(true) 448.00.0
Optional(false) 416.00.0
Optional(false) 384.00.0
Optional(false) 352.00.0
Optional(false) 320.00.0
Optional(false) 288.00.0
Optional(false) 256.00.0
Optional(false) 224.00.0
Optional(false) 192.00.0
Optional(false) 160.00.0
Optional(false) 128.00.0
Optional(false) 96.00.0
Optional(false) 64.00.0
Optional(false) 32.00.0
Optional(true) 0.00.0
```

And for the life of me I cannot see the difference? What am I missing??

Comment: you don't need to use semaphore because your for-loop is executed on just one queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the semaphore for? There is no *asynchronous thread stuff* in the code.

Just write

```
fileprivate func extractedFunc() {
    let t3 = "\(tileP[0 + issued].vertiSide - 32)\(tileP[0 + issued].horizSide)"
    if let ok = tileD[t3] {
        if !ok {
            for i in 0..<4 {
                let t0 = "\(tileP[i + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[i + issued].horizSide)"
                tileD[t0] = false
                tileP[i + issued].vertiSide -= 32
                let t1 = "\(tileP[i + issued].vertiSide)\(tileP[i + issued].horizSide)"
                tileD[t1] = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works!! What did I miss. Sure no semaphore needed, but where the difference in the code? Wait I seen it... an extra loop.

Comment: Your `for` loop in the second example is at the wrong place. If must be inside the `if !ok {` scope.